# How to add items to an arraylist using a scanner

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am taking Movie items from two files and adding both of the contents to an Arraylist "listOne" and "listTwo" by using a scanner to read the file contents. These two lists are then merged into one. However, while the scanner reads the files fine, my .add does not seem to be adding them to the ArrayLists properly.

I ensured that my merge and printwriter both work properly. Once I did that I did a print on what my scanner is reading and what the contents of the list are after being added. The scanner shows the proper information (i.e. A, J.Edgar, 2011, R, 1), but the list contents are giving me the base values (i.e. [Title: , Year: 0, Rating: null, Review: 0;]).

//This is my main class

```
 Scanner fileScanner; //Scanner to read TestInput1.txt
 Scanner fileScannerTwo; //Scanner to read TestInput2.txt
 ArrayList<Movie>listOne = new ArrayList<Movie>(); //first list
 ArrayList<Movie>listTwo = new ArrayList<Movie>(); //second list
 ArraryList<Movie>outList = new ArrayList<Movie>(); //merged&sorted list

 try{
      fileScanner = GetInputFile("Enter input filename: ");
      while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
      {
           String[] elements = fileScanner.nextLine().split(",");
           if(elements[0].equals("A")) //each movie has "A" to give ok
           {
                listOne.add(new Movie(elements[1], 
                Integer.parseInt(elements[2]), elements[3], 
                Integer.parseInt(elements[4])));
           }
      }
      //The same code but replace "listOne" with "listTwo"
 ..........
 ..........
      //PrintWriter that works properly
 ..........
 ..........

 }//end of try
 catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
      System.out.println("User terminated program");
 }
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
 //this is my Movie class
 private String movieTitle;
 private int releaseYear;
 private String rating;
 private int movieReview;

 public Movie(String Title, int Year, String rating, int Review)
 {
      movieTitle = "";
      releaseYear = 0;
      rating = "";
      movieReview = 0;
 }
 public String getTitle()
 {
      return movieTitle;
 }
 public int getYear()
 {
      return releaseYear;
 }
 public String getRating()
 //same stuff
 public int getReview()
 //same stuff

 public int compareTo(Movie other) //haven't used this yet, but will to sort
 {
    int makeComparison = this.movieTitle.compareTo(other.movieTitle);

    if(makeComparison != 0)
        return makeComparison;

    else
    {
        if(this.releaseYear != other.releaseYear)
            return this.releaseYear - other.releaseYear;

        else
            return 0;
    }
 }

 public String toString()
 {
      return String.format("Title: %s, Year: %s, Rating: %s, Review: %s;", 
                           this.movieTitle, this.releaseYear, this.rating, 
                           this.movieReview);
 }
```

I expect the output to look like
 [Title: J.Edgar, Year: 2011, Rating: R, Review: 1]
but I get
 [Title: , Year: 0, Rating: null, Review: 0;]

Here is a sample of the file: 
A,J. Edgar,2011,R,1

A,Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom,1984,PG,1

A,Mother's Day,2016,PG-13,4

A,History of the World Part I,1981,R,1

A,Crocodile Hunter,2002,PG,2

Comment: Can you share the code of your `Movie` class, as well as a sample of the file that you're parsing?

Comment: Are you sure that `GetInputFile` works properly? Try to add prints for each line you scan before splitting it.

Comment: @Jordan agreed, but mainly just the explicit-value constructor of op's `Movie` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

```
public Movie(String Title, int Year, String rating, int Review)
{
    movieTitle = "";
    releaseYear = 0;
    rating = "";
    movieReview = 0;
}
```

You're not using any of your constructor parameters.  You're just always setting the title to "", the release year to 0, etc.

Try this instead:

```
public Movie(String Title, int Year, String rating, int Review)
{
    movieTitle = Title;
    releaseYear = Year;
    this.rating = rating;
    movieReview = Review;
}
```

Also, consider following Java naming and code standards.  The generally-accepted standard is to always start variable names with a lower-case letter, and to write a constructor is to use the exact same names as your class's members, so:

```
public Movie(String movieTitle, int releaseYear, String rating, int movieReview) {
    this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
    this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.movieReview = movieReview;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed everything. I noticed you used this.rating.. Could you explain exactly what this does? Is it simply to show that we are using a different "rating"?

Comment: Yep.  The `this` keyword references the current instance of an object.  When you pass in a parameter with the same name as one of the class's members, the parameter name "shadows" the member name, and if you use the variable name by itself, you'll get the local, shadowed instance, and not the class-level member.  The `this` keyword scopes the variable reference as being the one up at the class level, and not the local variable.